# What is the Wordpress approach to custom data?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database

I'm new to Wordpress development. I want to create a stock portfolio management section on my site. In the admin panel I want to create a portfolio, enter stocks, what price they're purchased at, and track the latest price of those stocks, generating portfolio return statistics and so forth.

But I'm not sure the Wordpress-acceptable way of doing this. I know how to create settings forms and so on, but this doesn't seem to fit into that approach.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  I would recommend looking into custom post types.  WP makes it very easy to create your own types of data.  An example from WP core is the custom post type 'page' which differentiates between blog posts, and static page content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

As the comment from jdm2112 says, WordPress has the ability for you to create Custom Post Types. You can also make custom taxonomies, custom fields, and more. If you're new to this, then I would recommend you check out [Generate WP](https://generatewp.com/) as a resource. I find it's a great tool for getting a handle on what's possible.

**Make your CPT**
There are many plugins that can help you do this, but it is very easy to create your own.

If you need to get an idea of what that looks like, head over to the [WP post type generator](https://generatewp.com/post-type/) and play around with it for a bit. Once you feel like you've got a handle on it, you can add it to your theme functions.php, or even better, make your own plugin (my personal recommendation).

**Add Custom Fields**
You can make your [own meta boxes](https://generatewp.com/meta-box/) as well, but I actually recommend [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for this. Their pricing for Pro has gone up considerably, but their product is pretty dang amazing.

I hope that helps get you started. CPT and ACF are my WP bread and butter.

Comment: Thanks, I was just checking out that GenerateWP earlier. Do you think their premium generators are worth it or do you just use their free ones?

Comment: I just use the free ones. They're great for learning the basics, and once you've got a handle on that you don't need the premium ones.